# How to center a new div based on mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am trying to place a div in the center of my mouse course when I click a link

I have something like

```
<a id='btn' href='#' ><img src='test.png' /></a>
```

I want to see the new div overlay on my test.png and I want my mouse curse be the  center vertically and horizontally of the new div.

My js

```
var contentDiv = document.createElement('div');
var img        = document.createElement('img');

contentDiv.setAttribute('class','test1');

img.src='newimg.png';
contentDiv.appendChild(img);

$("#btn").on('click', function(e){
   $('body').append(contentDiv)
   var w = $(contentDiv).width()/2
   var h = $(contentDiv).height()/2
   var x = e.pageX - h  //- $(this).offset().left;
   var y = e.pageY - w  //- $(this).offset().top;
   $(contentDiv).css({top: y, left: x, 'transform': 'scale(.2)'})
    e.preventDefault();         
})
```

My code won't put my mouse cursor as the center of the new div. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks so much!

Comment: does test1 class set the position to like absolute or fixed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fxd8b/1/ please see the update. I need to remove width and height on css because I don't know the size of the new div

Comment: @PatrickEvans The problem was entirely different.  Look closely, what seems wrong? `x - height` and `y - width` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var x = e.pageX - w
var y = e.pageY - h
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fxd8b/2/)

That's the jQuery way to get the mouse position (`e.pageX`), so you could also do:

```
var x = e.clientX - w;
var y = e.clientY - h;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fxd8b/3/)

That's the pure-JS way.

Your problem was you were subtracting height from x and width from y, while it should be the other way around.  Remember, x is left and right, y is up and down.  In computer science, up decreases y, and down increases y, right increases x, left decreases x.

**Don't get them mixed up.**